# How to collect Ad impressions and Revenue data with Facebook Analytics?

Tags: facebook-analytics

How can i collect Ads impression and revenue data with Facebook Analytics?

For instance, i have google ads in the application, i would like to collect these data as if collected IAP data. In firebase, when you integrate your admob account, data of ads are collected automatically.

Is there a way to do it on Facebook Analytics either automatically or manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way currently for that, we do (our SDK both for iOS and Android) supports automatic in-app purchase instrumentation. But I guess your case it is more tricky, as this is not really an IAP. Allow me to propose two options:

1) Client side - you integrate FB SDK, hook to Ads impression callback (viewed and/or clicked) and fire custom event, like logEvent('ad', ad_id, ...) or standard event such as logPurchase() event.

Relevant link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events

2) Server side - export from GA / Firebase relevant events, and send them to our endpoint .../app_id/activities

Relevant link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api

Sincerely,
Eli from Facebook Analytics